CiviCRM Events approval process
I am trying to configure CiviCRM 5.73.2 for a non-profit organisation that helps children with bereavement. They run camps which children can sign up for and I have configured them as events. They also have volunteers that work in admin, support and as mentors (1 mentor for 1 child). I first thought of using Civivolunteer and add the volunteers in a project but that seems not successful. My thoughts now are:

create an event with Participant Approval and invite children (role: child) and volunteers (role: Well-Being Team) to register. ALl the registrations get the status "in cohort"
Three weeks out from the event review and select the participants and run the Action: Participant status - change and update the status to "Pending from approval". This then triggers the email to everyone for confirmation
Once the recipient confirms the email I would like to finalise the registration based on the role. The child would need to fill out details about their camp preferences, diet preferences, medical details, consent. The volunteer (Well-Being team) would need different details about diet, preferred role (mentor, nurse, admin, food preparation, cleanup, mentor), references, working with children status, consent.
For mentors I think I should either register the mentor/mentee name in a custom field or use relationships. The problem of relationships is that it is not limited to an event participant which is prone to errors. The problem of a custom field is that there is the possibility of making the relationship 1: many which is not what they want

I have some things I would like advise on:

how to differ the signup process dependent on the participant role where a child participant role needs a different signup profile than a well-being participant role
how best to relate mentors and mentees

Any smart ideas?

It's an unfortunate limitation of the old event registration process that it only supports one participant role.  Old extensions partially fixed this, but didn't address the need for different forms.  We worked around this by creating forms with Webform-CiviCRM, Caldera Forms-CiviCRM, etc.
These days, I think the best approach is to create multiple FormBuilder forms, which support participant registration.
As for linking mentors and mentees, this seems like a job for relationships. I'm not sure how custom fields reduce the possibility for error - and they're only accessible from one contact.  Relationships are visible on both sides.  You can use Mentor and Mentee contact subtypes (automatically added by filling out the FormBuilder form, if you like) that limit Mentor-Mentee relationships to folks who have the respective contact subtype.
If you have someone you work with (or are yourself) someone who writes code, you can also write an extension to further improve this process, but I assume you're looking for something that can be done without code.
